# how to create moving turtles out of a shapefile in Netlogo

Tags: gis, netlogo

I'm just starting with using Netlogo to create an Agent Based Model. I have two shapefiles I want to use: a network map of a city (line-shapefile) and a point-shapefile of scooters in the city. The idea is to have them drive through the city on the lines of the network shapefile. Since I am new to Netlogo, I only managed to load these shapefiles in my model. Could someone give me a headstart by helping me to create turtles from the scooter registrations (points) and let them move over the network lines. I have found little help so far on the internet and it won't work with trial and error. So far, my code is just this:

```
extensions [ gis ]

to load
  ca
  let network gis:load-dataset "Roads_Asmterdam.shp"

  foreach gis:feature-list-of network
  [ gis:set-drawing-color white
    gis:draw ? 0.3

  ]

  let people gis:load-dataset "scooters_Amsterdam.shp"
   foreach gis:feature-list-of people
  [ gis:set-drawing-color blue
    gis:draw people 3

  ]

end
```

So, as far as I know, I need a to go function where I want to move the turtles. And I need a function to create possible moving turtles out of the point-shapefile, but also I need to let them know to only use the lines instead of the whole area.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

After loading the lines shape file you need to convert these into a network of agents/turtles and link them. NetLogo doesn't do that for you, you need to iterate over all the features, line segments and coordinates yourself. Then you need to place the scooters onto the coordinates from the line network, and then you can "ask" them to move around.

Here's what I came up with:

```
extensions [ gis ]
globals [ roads-dataset scooter-dataset ]
breed [ nodes node ]
breed [ scooters scooter ]
breed [ walkers walker ]
walkers-own [ wlocation ]
scooters-own [slocation]

to setup
  ; reset
  clear-all
  reset-ticks

  ; load data set
  gis:load-coordinate-system (word "C:/Program Files/NetLogo 5.3.1/app/models/Code Examples/GIS/data/WGS_84_Geographic.prj")
  set roads-dataset gis:load-dataset "C:/shape/roads.shp"
  set scooter-dataset gis:load-dataset "C:/shape/scooter.shp"
  gis:set-world-envelope (gis:envelope-of roads-dataset)

  ; draw data set
  gis:set-drawing-color blue
  gis:draw roads-dataset 1

  make-road-network
end

to make-road-network
  clear-links
  let first-node nobody
  let previous-node nobody
  foreach gis:feature-list-of roads-dataset [ ; each polyline
    foreach gis:vertex-lists-of ? [ ; each polyline segment / coordinate pair
      foreach ? [ ; each coordinate
        let location gis:location-of ?
        if not empty? location [ ; some coordinates are empty []
          create-nodes 1 [
            set color green
            set size 1
            set xcor item 0 location
            set ycor item 1 location
            set hidden? true
            if first-node = nobody [
              set first-node self
            ]
            if previous-node != nobody [
              create-link-with previous-node
            ]
            set previous-node self
          ]
        ]
      ]
      set previous-node nobody
    ]
  ]
  ; connect adjacent polylines/roads
  ask nodes [ create-links-with other nodes in-radius 0.001 ]
end

to add-agents
  create-walkers 5 [
    set color red
    set wlocation one-of nodes
    move-to wlocation
  ]
end

to add-scooters
  foreach gis:feature-list-of scooter-dataset [ 
    foreach gis:vertex-lists-of ? [
      let location gis:location-of (first ?)

      create-scooters 1 [
        set color yellow
        set size 1
        set xcor item 0 location 
        set ycor item 1 location

        let nearest-node min-one-of (nodes in-radius 10)[distance myself]
        set slocation nearest-node
        move-to slocation
      ]
    ]
  ]
end

to go
  ask walkers [
    let new-location one-of [link-neighbors] of wlocation
    move-to new-location
    set wlocation new-location
  ]
  ask scooters [
    let new-location one-of [link-neighbors] of slocation
    move-to new-location
    set slocation new-location
  ]
end
```

Some resources and example code I found particularly helpful:

- [NetLogo Programming Guide](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#agents) & example models about "walking" and "networks" that come with NetLogo
- [NetLogo Bag of Tricks - Venice Example Code](http://backspaces.net/wiki/NetLogo_Bag_of_Tricks#Models)
- Duncan Golicher: [Importing points into Netlogo and forming a network](https://duncanjg.wordpress.com/2012/09/23/importing-points-into-netlogo-and-forming-a-network/)