# Create road network from shapefile in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I want to create a road network from Netlogo using a shapefile. My walkers are supposed to walk on roads to a specific goal. When I call the to go procedure I keep getting the error:

```
OF expected input to be an agent or agentset but got NOBODY instead.
error while walker 15 running OF
  called by procedure GO
  called by Button 'go'
```

My code so far is:

```
breed [nodes node]
breed [walkers walker]

walkers-own [
 origin
 myGoal
 wlocation  
]

to make-road-network
  clear-links
  let first-node nobody
  let previous-node nobody
  foreach gis:feature-list-of roads[ polyline ->
    foreach gis:vertex-lists-of  polyline [ segment ->
      foreach segment [coordinate ->
        let location gis:location-of coordinate
        if not empty? location [
          create-nodes 1 [
            set color blue
            set size 1
            set xcor item 0 location
            set ycor item 1 location
            set hidden? true
            if first-node = nobody [
              set first-node self
            ]
            if previous-node != nobody [
              create-link-with previous-node
            ]
            set previous-node self
          ]
        ]
      ]
      set previous-node nobody
    ]
  ]
  ; connect adjacent polylines/roads
  ask nodes [ create-links-with other nodes in-radius 0.001 ]
end


to go
  ask walkers[
    let new-location one-of [link-neighbors] of wlocation       ; here I am getting the error
    move-to new-location
    set wlocation new-location
    
  ]
end


to setupWalkers [nWalkers]
  sprout-walkers nWalkers  [
    set color 14
    set size 3 
    set shape "person"
    pen-down
    set origin  Spots
    set wlocation one-of nodes
    move-to wlocation
  ]
end
```

I followed the question ([how to create moving turtles out of a shapefile in Netlogo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26929504/how-to-create-moving-turtles-out-of-a-shapefile-in-netlogo)) and used the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could see two possible options for this error. The first possibility is that some nodes are not connected to any other nodes, but I don't know enough about the gis extension to comment on that.

The second possibility is that `let new-location one-of [link-neighbors] of wlocation` gives you the link-neighbors of your walker (which returns nobody), instead of the link-neighbors of your wlocation. The easy fix is to use brackets in order to specify whose link-neighbors you are interested in:

```
let new-location one-of ([link-neighbors] of wlocation)
```